# Unsupported parameters for (apache2_module) module

Tags: ansible

I am trying to enable apache modules on Ubuntu machine using the ansible-playbook. I am getting the following error

`FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to set module ['ssl', 'proxy', 'proxy_http', 'expires', 'headers'] to enabled:\n\nMaybe the module identifier (['ssl', 'proxy', 'proxy_http', 'expires', 'headers']_module) was guessed incorrectly.Consider setting the \"identifier\" option.", "rc": 1, "stderr": "ERROR: Module [ssl, does not exist!\nERROR: Module proxy, does not exist!\nERROR: Module proxy_http, does not exist!\nERROR: Module expires, does not exist!\nERROR: Module headers] does not exist!\n", "stderr_lines": ["ERROR: Module [ssl, does not exist!", "ERROR: Module proxy, does not exist!", "ERROR: Module proxy_http, does not exist!", "ERROR: Module expires, does not exist!", "ERROR: Module headers] does not exist!"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}`

The ansible playbook is as follows

```
  - name: Enable appropriate apache2 modules
    apache2_module:
      state: present
      name: "{{ modules }}"
    vars:
      modules:
      - ssl
      - proxy
      - proxy_http
      - expires
      - headers
```

Comment: Typo: `state=: present` should be `state: present`.

Comment: Noted and edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter [`name`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apache2_module_module.html#parameters) is `"Name of the module to enable/disable"`. A single name not a list of names. The list of names can be enabled in a loop. For example

```
  - name: Enable appropriate apache2 modules
    apache2_module:
      state: present
      name: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ modules }}"
    vars:
      modules:
      - ssl
      - proxy
      - proxy_http
      - expires
      - headers
```